# NSNumber integerValue returns incorrect value

Tags: objective-c

I have a very large integer returned by a json string from my server to my iphone app.  I usually use:

```
[results objectForKey:@"id"]
```

and things work fine but with a very large "id" the results don't match what was sent.  what is the standard method to get the integer value of the object returned by json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
  NSLog(@"%lld", [[results objectForKey@"id"] longLongValue]);
```

An `int` will have value between

INT_MIN:    -2147483648
INT_MAX:    2147483647

and a `long long` will have value between

LLONG_MIN:  -9223372036854775808
LLONG_MAX:  9223372036854775807

If its longer than that, you might try manipulating it as a string.